# CASE WHEN condition is met THEN WHERE logic

Tags: sql-server

I want to display temperatures that are greater or equal to 80, only if the weather field is hot. If the weather field is any other value, then display all temperatures.

```
SELECT field1, field2, etc, 

CASE 
   WHEN weather = 'hot' THEN temperature >= 80
   ELSE temperature 
END

FROM dbo.table
```

Error

```
I get an Incorrect Syntax near '>'
```

How should I re-write query to make it work?

Comment: What should it show when the wheather is hot and the temperature is less than 80?

Comment: It should display all the fields (including the temp field with values that are greater than or equal to 80). And if it is weather field is not hot then display all the fields (including temp field with all its values)

Comment: Your case expression is quite confusing. A case expression is used to return a single value but you have "temperature > 80". Perhaps your case expression is backwards? I just can't make heads or tails of what you are expecting for output here.

Comment: I don't understand what it is that you want at all....

Comment: I don't understand that first sentence. You want to display "Temperatures" that are >=80 when weather=hot. BUT... you also want to display "All Temperaturs" when weather<>hot. What is the difference between display "Temperaturs" and "All Temperatures". Your sentence reads like nonsense. Perhaps I don't understand your schema/data and that would help make sense of it all.

Comment: @JNevill yeah, I don't get it either. It would be better if op posted some sample data and desired result

Comment: I only want temperature >= 80 where weather = hot

Comment: I only want temperature >= 80 where weather = hot

Comment: Do you see how confused can be a simple question?     Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: @user3062459 It is still very unclear. Perhaps "I only want values from field "Temperature" where the Temperatur >= 80 AND Weather='Hot'? This would really be helped if you could share some sample data and your desired results since writing it out in English doesn't seem to helping us understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to filter the rows. So it should be a `where` clause.

```
select *
from table
where temperature >= 80
    or weather != 'hot'
```

Explanation of the where clause:

say

```
condition a = { weather == hot },
    so not_a = { weather != hot }
condition b = { temperature >= 80 }
```

What you want is all row where weather is hot and temperature >= 80 and when it's not hot, then all the temperatures:

which makes:

```
 = a.b + not_a
 = (a + not_a).(b + not_a)
 = (true).(b + not_a)
 = b + not_a
 = temperature >= 80 or weather != hot
```

So writing

```
where temperature >= 80 or weather != hot
```

is equivalent to

```
where (weather = 'hot' and temperature >= 80) or weather != hot
```

Comment: I only want temperature >= 80 where weather = hot

Comment: Yes. It works that way only. I'll add the explanation. It's all boolean algerbra really.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing what [Gurwinder Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6348498/gurwinder-singh) correctly proposed would be more explicitly:

```
select *
from table
where 
    (temperature >= 80 and weather = 'hot')
    or
    (weather != 'hot')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this case

```
SELECT field1, field2, etc, 

CASE 
   WHEN weather = 'hot' and  temperature >= 80 then temperature
   ELSE 0 -- Or null, it will depend on your logic 
END

FROM dbo.table
```

This case will only show the temperature when the weather is hot and temperature greater than 80. You can alter the else to return Null